# Character Sequence matching in a loop in R

Tags: r, sequence

I am quite a novice in R. Apology for asking a basic question in advance.

I have a dataframe, which looks like:

```
head(df)
  cr_id                      description       region       type   status
1     1 Grant system adminstrator rights         EMEA      audit approved
2     2     grant access to all products           UK     system  pending
3     3                 change in design Asia Pacific      audit approved
4     4                 change in design           UK regulatory  pending
5     5      More robust system required Asia Pacific     system  pending
6     6  Volume productivity for NA 2016           UK      audit approved
```

Now suppose I have new description entered by the user captured in the variable new_cr. I can use the following for getting the similarity between any 2 descriptions as:

```
library(fuzzywuzzyR)
init = SequenceMatcher$new(string1 = df$description, string2 = new_cr)
init$ratio
```

But can anyone help me to put this into the loop or any other efficient method to get all the similar descriptions (in the entire dataframe) above a certain threshold (0.8) in a list for further processing?

Comment: I am not quite sure I've exactly understood what you are after. Have a look at the newly edited answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a for loop you can do the following

```
ratios <- numeric(nrow(df))
for (ind in 1 : nrow(df)){
  init <- SequenceMatcher$new(string1 = df$description[ind], string2 = new_cr)
  ratios[ind] <- init$ratio()
}
```

Another approach to obtaining `ratios`

```
ratios <- sapply(df$description, function(x) 
                SequenceMatcher$new(string1 = x, string2 = new_cr)$ratio())
```

Now retain only the desired rows

```
new_df <- df[which(ratios > 0.8), ]
```

If you just want similar descriptions, you can do the following.

```
df$description[ratios > 0.8]
```